# How can I check for text in TextInput so I can disable other TextInput

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language, textinput

I'm building an App that calculates electrical parameters. It's a symple project, but it is my first.

I'm using the KiVy library because I fond it's a easy one to start. I want to check for entries inside the textInput windows, so if I enter with 2 values, the program disables field that can be evaluetaded based on the values entered.

Don't mind the variables, methods and Ids. Not native english speaker here.

My View Code it the following:

.kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
<WarningPopup@Popup>:
    message: message
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: "Aviso"
    size_hint: None, None
    width: grid.width + dp(25)
    height: grid.height + root.title_size + dp(48)
    
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size
        padding: [10, 5]
        cols: 1
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "center"
            anchor_y: "bottom"
            size_hint: None, None
            height: message.height
            width: max(message.width, butt.width)
            Label: 
                id: message
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                padding: [10, 5]
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "center"
            anchor_y: "bottom"
            size_hint: None, None
            height: butt.height
            width: max(message.width, butt.width)
            Button:
                id: butt
                text: 'Fehcar'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                padding: [10, 5]
                on_release: root.dismiss()



<ParamCalcWindow>:
    name: 'Calculadora'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 0.95, 0.95
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.09
            
            ToggleButton:
                id: trifasico
                text: 'Trifásico'
                group: 'fases'
                state: 'normal'
                on_press: root.check_toggles()

            ToggleButton:
                id: monofasico
                text: 'Monofásico'
                group: 'fases'
                state: 'down'
                on_press: root.check_toggles()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.09

                
            TextInput:
                id: PotenciaAparente
                hint_text: "Potência Aparente [VA]"
                text: ""
                halign: 'center'
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
                input_filter: 'float'
                multiline: False
            
            
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.09

            TextInput:
                id: PotenciaAtiva
                hint_text: "Potência Ativa [W]"
                text: ""
                halign: 'center'
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
                input_filter: 'float'
                multiline: False
                

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.09

            TextInput:
                id: PotenciaReativa
                hint_text: "Potência Reativa [VAr]"
                text: ""
                halign: 'center'
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
                input_filter: 'float'
                multiline: False


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.09

            TextInput:
                id: cosphi
                hint_text: "cos \u03C6"
                text: ""
                halign: 'center'
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
                input_filter: 'float'
                multiline: False
            
            TextInput:
                id: phi
                hint_text: "\u00B1\u03C6°"
                text: ""
                halign: 'center'
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
                input_filter: 'float'
                multiline: False

            TextInput:
                id: Reatancia
                hint_text: "Indutivo Capacitivo"
                text: ""
                halign: 'center'
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
                input_filter: 'float'
                
        
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.09

            TextInput:
                id: Tensao
                hint_text: "Tensão [V]"
                text: ""
                halign: 'center'
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.09

            TextInput:
                id: Corrente
                hint_text: "Corrente [A]"
                text: ""
                halign: 'center'
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.01
            Label:
                text: ""
                size_hint: 1, 0.01

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.09

            Button:
                id: Limpar
                text: "Limpar"
                size_hint: 0.4, 1
                on_release: root.clear_all()

            Label:
                text: ""
                size_hint: 0.2, 1

            Button:
                id: Calcular
                text: "Calcular"
                size_hint: 0.4, 1
                on_release: root.get_entries()
```

View file:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class WarningPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WarningPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
        self.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)

    def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = instance.pos
        self.rect.size = instance.size


class ParamCalcWindow(Screen):

    toggles_previous_state = "normaldown"

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(ParamCalcWindow, self).__init__(**kw)

    def clear_entry(self, instance: TextInput):
        instance.text = ""
        pass

    def clear_all(self):
        self.ids.PotenciaAparente.text = ""
        self.ids.PotenciaAtiva.text = ""
        self.ids.PotenciaReativa.text = ""
        self.ids.cosphi.text = ""
        self.ids.phi.text = ""
        self.ids.Reatancia.text = ""
        self.ids.Tensao.text = ""
        self.ids.Corrente.text = ""
        pass

    def get_entries(self):
        return [
            float(self.ids.PotenciaAparente.text)
            if self.ids.PotenciaAparente.text
            else None,
            float(self.ids.PotenciaAtiva.text) if self.ids.PotenciaAtiva.text else None,
            float(self.ids.PotenciaReativa.text)
            if self.ids.PotenciaReativa.text
            else None,
            self.filter_TextInput(self.ids.cosphi, lower_limit=0, upper_limit=1),
            self.filter_TextInput(self.ids.phi, lower_limit=-90, upper_limit=90),
            self.ids.Reatancia.text if self.ids.Reatancia.text else None,
            float(self.ids.Tensao.text) if self.ids.Tensao.text else None,
            float(self.ids.Corrente.text) if self.ids.Corrente.text else None,
        ]

    def filter_TextInput(
        self, instance: TextInput, lower_limit: float, upper_limit: float
    ) -> float | None:
        text = instance.text

        if not text:
            return None
        value = float(text)
        if lower_limit <= value <= upper_limit:
            return instance
        warning = WarningPopup()
        warning.message.text = instance.hint_text + " fora do intervalo permitido"
        self.clear_entry(instance)
        warning.open()

    def get_mode(self):
        return [self.ids.trifasico.state, self.ids.monofasico.state]

    def check_toggles(self):

        if self.ids.trifasico.state == self.ids.monofasico.state:
            if self.toggles_previous_state == "normaldown":
                self.ids.trifasico.state = "down"
                self.ids.monofasico.satte = "normal"
            else:
                self.ids.trifasico.state = "normal"
                self.ids.monofasico.state = "down"

        self.toggles_previous_state = (
            self.ids.trifasico.state + self.ids.monofasico.state
        )

# tests
class ParamCalcApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ParamCalcWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ParamCalcApp().run()
```

If there's any formating strangement, it's the autoformating fault lol.

Given the code, output is [image]

I want the program to identify that I've entered some parameter so it disables the fields that will be evalueted like this:

[image]

Comment: PS.: Improve the code in anyway you see fit. My .Kv file is full of repetitions that could be bettered on the Python side. But as I said.  this is my first kivy program.

Answer (score 1):

In your `kv` file, under the `TextInput` of interest, you can add:

```
on_text: app.text_changed(self, self.text)
```

And, in your `app` class, add a method:

```
def text_changed(self, instance, text):
```

This will trigger the execution of `text_changed()` whenever the `text` of the `TextInput` changes (literally, on every change).

You could use `on_text_validate:` instead of `on_text:`. That will only trigger the method when the user hits `Enter`.